# Why member variable doesn't follow the recursion return rules?

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm using a recursion to calculate two variables. What confused me is when I define a variable out of the method as a member variable, it returns the value which is last assigned to the variable instead of the first assigned to the variable? Why does this happen?

```
class Program
{
    int a = 3;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        int result = program.Test();
        Console.WriteLine(result); // result = 0
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private int Test()
    {
        a--;
        if(a != 0)
        {
            Test();
        }
        return a;
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        int result = program.Test(3);
        Console.WriteLine(result); // result = 2
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private int Test(int a)
    {
        a--;
        if(a != 0)
        {
            Test();
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

I wonder how did this happen? Is there some other rules that influence the the recursion return order? To me, I think if only I don't use out or ref, it should be make a copy of the member variable for calculate. So is anyone could help me find the reason?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry I copy the same code twice. I've update the post! Thanks!

Comment: @Grant I think before the recursion ended, it uses the last value get from previous method not using the value of member variable. And the debug process did show that a is 2, 1, 0 for both script. The different is that when the recursion returns, the first script return 0,0,0 for three times while the second returns 0,1,2

Comment: Please post [MCVE]. There is no way second code would compile as shown (you did not show no-argument version of `Test()` that is called there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as intended:

```
 private int Test(int a){
            a--;
            if (a != 0)
                return Test(a);
            return a;
        }
```

if you are not returning the result of test, it will just run the method then go to the next statement of the method. In your case, without `return Test(a)` it just doesn't do anything with the result of Test(int a).

Edit:

An example of pass by reference to have a similar working code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program program = new Program();
            int a = 3;
            int result = program.Test(ref a);
            Console.WriteLine(result); // result = 0
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private int Test(ref int a)
        {
            a--;
            if (a != 0)
            {
                Test(ref a);
            }
            return a;
        }
```

Comment: I know if not return it will go to the next statement. But what I'm wondering is that why it returns different values?

Comment: In c# by default an int is not passed by reference, you need to specify it explicitly. In your case you would need to pass a by reference (see edited answer)

Comment: I don't think a ref is needed here as I'm not intended to pass the return value to the member variable. What I concern is why Test(a) and Test(3) returns different value in this case

Comment: If you want to see exactly what it does you may want to use a break point and run it step by step to see how it behaves. The two code snippets you showed are completely different. Since the first one uses a variable declared in the class Program, your method could be void and not return anything because each time you call it, it affects this instance's of a so regardless of giving a paremeter or a return  it will decrease a by 1 every time Test() is called. In the second one, you give a paremeter called a so the method will operate on that paremeter, because it is passed by value, 1/2

Comment: it doesn't matter if you run Test() because you do not do anything with the value of it in your if statement. So this is what happens in the second snippet: Test(3) --> 3-- = 2 then 2>0 so Test(2) returns 1 and within it it does Test(1) and it returns 0. However, you are not using it everytime the method is called so it exits the if statement and goes to return a and in the first call it was equal to 2. I hope this was a bit more clear 2/2

Comment: Thanks David. I got what you meant and debug the code step by step. I think I may get the point. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `a` is changed by `Test()`. Each call of `Test` use the same variable `a`.

If you want to have a copy, make it yourself:

```
private int Test()
{
    int b = a--;
    if(a != 0)
    {
        Test();
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't enunciate myself. I mean in my case, when using a member variable in a method, it just make a copy of the value of the member variable instead of using the same reference. So it should get the same result in recursion compared to using an int directly. But I get different ones when using member variable

Answer (score 0):

The `this` keyword is omitted, this makes the member variable look like a normal local variable, but they are different in principle. The member variables are refer to the same instance.

```
private int Test()
{
    this.a--;
    if(this.a != 0)
    {
        this.Test();
    }
    return this.a;
}
```

Comment: Yes, The member variable is refer to the same instance. But I assume when using a member variable in a method, it just make a copy of the value of the member variable instead of using the same reference. So it should get the same result in recursion. But I get different ones when using member variable

Comment: The local variable is a copy, the member variable isn't.